# jQuery: How to detect radio button change caused by other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

have a table with a radio button inside each . The problem is, the table is already generated for me and there is an event attached on the tds that when they are clicked, the state of the radio button inside is also changed. I do not have control on the scripts generated.

Is there a way to detect the value change on the radio button (no click/keypress) or overwrite the built-in event on the tds? I need to do something when the state of the radio button is checked.

I'm using jQuery and here's my current code:

```
$( 'input[type=radio]' ).on( 'change', function() {
    var $this = $( this );
        if( $this.is( ':checked' ) ) alert( 'a' );
} );
```

Comment: no there is not... if the state is changed by another script then the change event will not get triggered automatically.. it has to be done manually.. if you don't have control over the script then it is a tough luck

Comment: one possible solution is to understand which events can change the radio state and handle them at a higher level by making use of event propagation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add another click event to the td's and trigger the radio buttons change event.

```
$('td').on('click',function() {
    $('input[type=radio]', this).trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Kiiro: this will need to be paired with the original code above (not replacing it)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I interpreted this as 'no control over the scripts already there' .. so with an additional script, this could be done. If I'm wrong, sorry!

Comment: @MildlyInteresting thanks for your answer, It worked like a charm! Though I don't know what the ", this" in the selector does, I'll have to read up on that.

Comment: @KiiroSora09 The `this` equals the `td` the click happened on. The jQuery call accepts a second argument, the context. `$(selector, context)` If you pass a context, the selector returns only items within that context. In your case, the radio button in the clicked `td` instead of all radio buttons in the document.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting Wow, I learned a lot today, I was not able to use context before. Thanks.